# How to fill a new column after two for loops?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. Each one of them has an `id_right`. I want to make a verification that if the `id_right` from the `df_orders` is in the `df_events`, a new column named `open_orders` returns 0 or 1 (False or True).

This is my **df_events**

|  | id_left | type | id_right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a752c3dd-211b-32cf-263a-c95a600e2498 | bias | 35108 |
| 183 | 8e3ef49e-6c27-08bc-1c57-8c3db5d15d52 | payload | 35108 |
| 236 | 4cbef24a-a796-455c-9f23-9f6f32d47707 | rack | 17459 |

This is my **df_orders**

|  | id_left | priority | id_right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2cc99d82-991f-47e3-bf52-381f6e3fae1a | medium | 17761 |
| 1 | 2ee76487-bbd4-46d1-a66c-89f22be2bfbd | urgent | 17958 |
| 2 | 89f22be2bfbd-47e3-9f6f32d47707 | normal | 35108 |

- They don't have the same amount of indexes
- I thought in double for loop so it can iterate in all rows. If I just used a single for loop, the output would always be a different `id_right`.
- Dispite in the tables above the id_right don't match, it's just an example of the header.

This is what I have already tried, but the outputs are always 0.

```
for i in df_orders['id_right']:

    for x in df_events['id_right']:
        if i == x:
            df_events['open_orders'] = 1
       
        elif i != x:
            df_events['open_orders'] = 0
        else:
             pass
```

I'm expecting this kind of output in the **df_events**:

|  | id_left | type | id_right | open_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a752c3dd-211b-32cf-263a-c95a600e2498 | bias | 35108 | 1 |
| 183 | 8e3ef49e-6c27-08bc-1c57-8c3db5d15d52 | payload | 35108 | 1 |
| 236 | 4cbef24a-a796-455c-9f23-9f6f32d47707 | rack | 17459 | 0 |

Anyone has any tips?

Comment: Can you please also add `df_orders` and `df_events` for the expected output?

Comment: For sure! Just one moment

Comment: @AndrejKesely I tried to improve my question. Check it, is it any better?

Comment: Your provided sample data, should produce your expected output. Currently there's no overlap in your samples, so either update your output or your sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin) to test `id_right`'s presence in `df_events['id_right]` and convert to type `int` with [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype).

```py
import pandas as pd

df_orders = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_left': ['a752c3dd-211b-32cf-263a-c95a600e2498',
                '8e3ef49e-6c27-08bc-1c57-8c3db5d15d52',
                '4cbef24a-a796-455c-9f23-9f6f32d47707'],
    'type': ['bias', 'payload', 'rack'],
    'id_right': [35108, 35108, 17459]
})
df_events = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_left': ['2cc99d82-991f-47e3-bf52-381f6e3fae1a',
                '2ee76487-bbd4-46d1-a66c-89f22be2bfbd',
                '89f22be2bfbd-47e3-9f6f32d47707'],
    'type': ['medium', 'urgent', 'normal'],
    'id_right': [17761, 17958, 35108]
})

new_df = df_orders.copy()
new_df['open_orders'] = new_df['id_right'] \
    .isin(df_events['id_right']) \
    .astype(int)

# For Print
print(new_df)
```

Output:

|  | id_left | type | id_right | open_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a752c3dd-211b-32cf-263a-c95a600e2498 | bias | 35108 | 1 |
| 1 | 8e3ef49e-6c27-08bc-1c57-8c3db5d15d52 | payload | 35108 | 1 |
| 2 | 4cbef24a-a796-455c-9f23-9f6f32d47707 | rack | 17459 | 0 |

---

If modifying `df_orders` is okay, the new column can be added directly to the DataFrame:

```py
df_orders['open_orders'] = df_orders['id_right'] \
    .isin(df_events['id_right']) \
    .astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd attempt to do this in a different way, I'm gonna rephrase what you need as

> "produce a new dataframe that contains `id_right` and `open_orders` columns where `open_orders` would contain **1** if the respective `id_right` existed in both input dataframe, otherwise it'd be **0**"

I'm assuming that only the first dataframe needs to be checked and that the order and index doesn't matter.

### Steps

Now the steps to do this would be would be

- For the second dataframe, add a column `open_orders` and fill it with 1
- do a left join (using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)) on slices of the dataframe containing only the needed columns
- [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on `open_orders` with 0s

### Code

```py
df_orders["open_orders"] = 1
df_merged = df_events["id_right"].merge(df_orders[["id_right", "open_orders"]], how="left")
df_merged["open_orders"] = df_merged["open_orders"].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hey, Jimmar! This solution was quite interesting. Plus, you made a much better phrase then me. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @RodrigoBrust you are welcome, note that generally `isin` is slower than `merge` so consider which one to use depending on the size of the dataset

Comment: Hm, that's interesting to know. I really used the `isin` function because for now I needed some output to keep on building my algorithm. Latter, I'll try with this solution you provided me. The main reason didn't use was due the merge of dataframes. But anyways, as I said, in the near future I'll try to adapt you solution.

Comment: @RodrigoBrust the merge is non destructive, it creates a new dataframe (well, without copying data) while keeping your old data intact, good luck 

Comment: I'm a little confused. Merge function is not destructive. Okay. So, does this mean that new rows are not added, just columns, right?

Comment: @RodrigoBrust nothing is added, note that I'm saving it in a new df called `df_merged` so the previous ones are not touched, most of pandas functions returns a new dataframe (unless you supply `inplace = True`)

Comment: uhhh, I see now! Tomorrow I'll try it again and check the performance. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231662/discussion-between-rodrigo-brust-and-jimmar).